# Writing shouldQuarantine prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor, prototype

I need this to determine if any of the passengers are isHealthy =false then quarantine the wagon. I may have an issue on the join prototype as well. The isHealthy is only triggered if they eat and have no food. So it is possible for them to eat, and then have no food but not trigger isHealthy.

```
const Traveler = function (travelerName) {
    this.name = travelerName;
    this.food = 1;
    this.isHealthy = true;
};
Traveler.prototype.hunt = function () {
    this.food += 2;
    console.log(this.food);
};
Traveler.prototype.eat = function () {
    this.food -= 1;
    if (this.food === 1) {
    } else {
        this.food === 0;
        this.isHealthy = false;
    }
    console.log(this.food);
};

console.log(new Traveler("John"));

function Wagon(capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.passengers = [];
}
console.log(new Wagon(4));
Wagon.prototype.getAvailableSeatCount = function () {
    let seatingCapacity = this.capacity - this.passengers.length;
    console.log(seatingCapacity);
    return seatingCapacity;
};

Wagon.prototype.join = function (traveler) {
    console.log(this.capacity);
    let currentCapacity = this.capacity;
    if (currentCapacity <= this.passengers.length) {
        this.currentCapacity = 0;
    } else if (this.getAvailableSeatCount != 0) {
        this.passengers.push(traveler);
    }

    console.log(this.passengers);
};
Wagon.prototype.shouldQuarantine = function () {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.passengers.length; i++) {
        if (this.passengers[i].isHealthy) {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

Wagon.prototype.totalFood = function () {
    let totalFood = "";
    this.passengers.forEach(this.food);
    console.log(this.food);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `eat` method of the `Traveler` class, first check if there is any food. If there is, then subtract one and check if the food is now empty. If it is then set `isHealthy` to `false`.

```
Traveler.prototype.eat = function () {
  if (this.food > 0) {
    this.food -= 1;

    if (this.food === 0) {
      this.isHealthy = false;
    } 
  }
};
```

Subsequently you should also modify your `hunt` method to make your traveler healthy again after hunting.

```
Traveler.prototype.hunt = function () {
  this.food += 2;
  this.isHealthy = true;
};
```

In the `shouldQuarantine` method of the `Wagon` class, instead of checking if all passengers are healthy, check if anyone of them is **not** healthy and return `true` if that is the case.

If everyone is healthy, the loop will finish. Return `false` after the loop.

```
Wagon.prototype.shouldQuarantine = function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.passengers.length; i++) {
    if (!this.passengers[i].isHealthy) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
};
```

Alternatively you could use the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method on the `this.passengers` array to check if any of the passenger isn't healthy.

```
Wagon.prototype.shouldQuarantine = function () {
  return this.passengers.some(
    passenger => passenger.isHealthy === false
  );
};
```

The `join` method can be simplyfied. You only need the result from `this.getAvailableSeatCount()` to see if there is any room. Add the traveler if the result is not `0`.

```
Wagon.prototype.join = function (traveler) {
  const availableSeats = this.getAvailableSeatCount();
  if (availableSeats !== 0) {
    this.passengers.push(traveler);
  }
};
```

I also noticed that the `totalFood` method doesn't work as expected, but I'll let this one up to you. Hint: `totalFood` should be a number. Loop over every `passenger` and add the amount of `food` to the `totalFood` value.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I very much appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Please feel free to ask any questions if you have them.

Comment: I dont have any more questions right now. I will be working on part 2 tomorrow though. Perhaps I will have additional questions then.

Comment: Hey Emiel - For the next part of this project. I need to refactor both the Traveler and the Wagon to classes instead of constructor and prototypes. Any suggestions on how I should do that?

Comment: Look into [examples of the `class` syntax](https://javascript.info/class) and rewrite it. The code inside the function blocks remains the same. The way you define your constructor, methods and properties change. Be sure to create a new question if you need specific help converting your code.